# Show word file from SQL to web page

Tags: c#, sql, .net, file, binary

I have stored .doc/.docx and pdf files in SQL db in binary format. I want to show them in a web browser and I used the following code. Here there is no problem for .pdf files, it showing correctly in web page. But for .doc/.docx there is an unformat data is shown in web page.

```
DataSet ds = GetData(proID);
            Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Resume"];
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset ="";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString() == ".doc" || ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString() == ".docx")
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            }
            else if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString() == ".pdf")
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            }
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

The if condition for .doc/.docx is not working.. How ever it took content type for .doc/.docx files as "text/html". Can anyone help me to done this?

Comment: Did you just try the obvious as "application/ms-word"

Comment: Ya.. I tried with "application/ms-word". But it downloads the .aspx page

Comment: I tried it with "Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";". But it downloads the word file from DB where as I want to show in browser/web page

Answer (score 0):

Below should work.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. I tried this. It downloads the actual word file. But i need to show in web page/browser

Comment: I have updated the answer. Need not use content disposition

Comment: Ya.. I tried with "application/vnd.ms-word". But it downloads the .aspx page

Comment: Try with  `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";`

Comment: @DheerajRoy and Nagaraj - It downloads the actual word file. But i need to show in web page/browser ..

Comment: DataSet ds = GetData(proID);
            Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Resume"];
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset ="";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString(); //  Here content type is application/pdf OR application/vnd.ms-word        
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                Response.Flush();

Comment: @KaviSuja why don't you try to store a file in server rather than storing and fetching from database..

Comment: Thinking of that.. because of limited time i am looking on this